# Delphi - Get Hint/tooltip/help from any application created from any languages

Tags: delphi

I have a project that will require me to get the Hint/tooltip/help text from application controls, so far I have created the code that will get the hint/tooltip/help text from standard tooltip control and Hint from Delphi App. Is there a way to get the hint/tooltip/help text without specifying what class or language that the application created from?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you need to understand is that applications are free to display hints using whatever implementation they please. So in full generality, there is a limitless number of different ways that hints could be implemented. There is no one size fits all solution.

Comment: Thank you David, seems we need to understand first class and behavior on how this will be triggered